# Azure Pipelines Environments and Helm

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, kubernetes-helm

I have an azure pipeline that I am using to generate and push helm charts in. Within this pipeline I have a deployment stage that uses the `HelmDeploy0` task. This task requires a `kubernetesServiceEndpoint`. Consequentially, I have also opted to use Pipeline environments and have configured my dev Kubernetes cluster as my Dev Environment for use in the pipeline. I am unsure ohow this task is going to use this environment as I have to assume that Azure DevOps, upon using the environment, must be authenticating with the cluster, thus, the helm chart should simply install. Unfortunately the `HelmDeploy0` task requires this serviceendpoint key. Any insight would be appreciated. Below is a snippet of the pipeline stage.

```
- stage: Dev
  displayName: Deploy to Dev
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master'))
  jobs: 
  - deployment:
    
    displayName: Deploy $(projName)
    environment: 'Dev'
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        preDeploy:
          steps:
            - task: HelmInstaller@1
              inputs:
                helmVersionToInstall: latest
        deploy:
          steps:
            - task: HelmDeploy@0
              displayName: Install Helm Chart
              inputs: 
                command: install
                chartName: $(REGISTRY_NAME)/helm/$(projName)
                arguments: --version $(tag)
                releaseName: $(projName)
```

NOTE: Yes I know variables cannot be used as the display name, it's there to protect any IP right now.

Comment: Hi Did you get a chance to check out below answer. How did it go?

Comment: Your suggestion worked out. I was even able to build a deployment template to pass this info. Thanks so much! I have marked your answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to explicitly specify your Kubernetes cluster resource name in the Environment section. See below:

```
- deployment: 
  environment:               
    name: Dev   # name of the environment to run this job on.
    resourceName: cluster-resource-name # name of the resource in the environment to record the deployments against
    resourceType: Kubernetes
  strategy:
    ...
```

You can also try using the shorten syntax: `environment: environmentName.resourceName`. If the shorten syntax failed to find the resource, you need to use above syntax to provide the `resourceType`. See document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#environment).

The steps of the deployment job automatically inherit the service connection details from resource targeted by the deployment job.

> You can scope the target of deployment to a particular resource within the environment. This allows you to record deployment history on a specific resource within the environment. The steps of the deployment job automatically inherit the service connection details from resource targeted by the deployment job.

Check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#environment) for information.